On a MacOS M1 with Packer, how to access a QEMU VM with an IP address in the same range as on the Macbook M1?
Does anybody have an example how to build a Linux VM with Packer with QEMU installed on the Macbook M1 and access it from the Macbook itself?
I can build the VM, but I can't ping the Internet from the created VM or ping the VM from mu Macbook.
packer {
  required_plugins {
    qemu = {
      version = ">= 1.1.0"
      source  = "github.com/hashicorp/qemu"
    }
  }
}

source "qemu" "opensuse" {
  vm_name                   = "testvm"
  iso_url                   = "opensuse-leap-15.6"
  iso_checksum              = "2213213>"
  boot_command              = ["<esc><enter><wait> linux textmode=1 autoyast=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/autoinst.xml <wait5><enter>"]
  boot_wait                 = "5s"
  cpus                      = "2"
  memory                    = "4096"
  disk_size                 = "50G"
  disk_compression          = true
  accelerator               = "tcg"
  http_directory            = "."
  http_interface            = "en4"

  output_directory          = "output/"

  ssh_username              = var.ssh_username
  ssh_password              = var.env_ssh_password
  ssh_timeout               = var.ssh_timeout

  use_default_display       = true

  net_device                = "virtio-net"

  qemuargs = [
      ["-display", "cocoa"],
  ]
}

build {
  sources = ["source.qemu.opensuse"]
}

Can anybody help me with this? Greatly appreciated
